# Using the Matrix Filter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, matrix

I'm able to get CSS rotation setup for all browsers, but now I need to do this inside Javascript.
I'm using jQuery as well and currently the following:

```
.css({ '-ms-filter':"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.9659258262890683, M12=-0.2588190451025207, M21=0.2588190451025207, M22=0.9659258262890683, SizingMethod='auto expand')"  });
```

is not working. The same code in the CSS works perfectly. I've tried escaping apostrophes, but it didn't work. Any ideas? I first need to set the values initially, so just a simple .CSS as show above. Then the values are updated within the following function:

```
function rotate(degree){ 
if((ievers==6)||(ievers==7)||(ievers==8)){
current_obj.css({
/* IE8 */
'-ms-filter':'"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation='+degree+')"',/* IE<8 */'filter':'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation='+degree+')'});
} else {
/* HANDLE OTHER BROWSERS */ ...
};
rotatetimer = setTimeout(function(){ rotate(++degree); },10 );}
```

This code is setup and works in everything except IE7/8 (because of the (rotation=x) only allowing you 4 options for rotation. So I'm trying to swap that line out with the .Matrix and dynamically calculate the SIN/COS values on the fly.

Comment: Are you trying to apply this in a non-IE browser?

Comment: No, just IE8 right now... I'll add additional code to place it context.

Comment: jQuery version is needed too. What happens if you try `msFilter` or `ms-Filter` instead of `-ms-filter`?

Comment: No result... same thing: 'ms-filter':"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.9659258262890683, M12=-0.2588190451025207, M21=0.2588190451025207, M22=0.9659258262890683, SizingMethod='auto expand')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current_obj[0].style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.9659258262890683, M12=-0.2588190451025207, M21=0.2588190451025207, M22=0.9659258262890683, SizingMethod='auto expand')";

worked for me. Also, as I see, the BasicImage filter's rotation value is measured in ninety-degrees increment. More references on filters: [MSDN filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms673539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, this seems to be getting a lot closer, but now I'm running into a problem with actually getting the object by class to work with. I've found a ton of functions for GetElementByClass, but they don't seem to be working and just keep throwing the same error: Unable to set value of the property 'filter': object is null or undefined

Comment: Well, it's easy to get elements by class, since you are using jQuery, and also you can loop through them with the each function, like this:

jQuery('.className').each(function(){

 this.style.filter = "something";
});